# Cannot get xmlhttprequest.responseText from JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xmlhttprequest

I'm newbie with JQuery.

I got this function

```
function verify_at_bd() {
  var u = "foo";
  var p = "bar";

  return $.post('auth.php', {
      name: u,
      password: p,
      mobile: ''
    },
    function(result) {
      return result;
    }, 'json');
}
```

If I do a `console.log(verify_at_bd())` I'm getting an xmlhttprequest but cannot access to responseText property. I'm using `header("Content-Type: application/json")` in the PHP script.

I'm using firefox 3.6 on OS X.

Comment: there is a structural flaw in this code: the function will never produce a result because $.post is asynchronous. if you include the code that calls the verify_at_bd function, somebody may show you how to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here goes:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'auth.php',
  data: {name: 'foo', password: 'bar', mobile: ''},
  success: function(result, textStatus, xmlhttprequest){
        console.log( $.parseJSON(xmlhttprequest.responseText).status);
    },
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Well, firstly, the XHR must be in readyState 4 to get responseText.

Secondly, it looks to me like you are abusing $.post(). It is an asynchronous call, you do not process the result of $.post(), you deal with the result in your success method (function(result)).

If you really need the reponseText, then add a few more arguments to your success function and catch the xhr there.

See jquery docs for $.post to see which arg is the xhr.

Answer (score 0):

As [@code poet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242897/code-poet) said, you're utilizing the [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method in an awkward way. It is an asynchronous call, so you can't expect to see the result returned to you immediately until the AJAX POST request completes. If you could post the code you've written to handle the JSON you expect this `function` to return, it would be easier to advise you on a proper way to structure your `$.post` response.